# Combinations with a certain number of symbol repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, multisets

Help please formulate a formula for calculating the number of all possible combinations for these conditions:

- The string must contain the a certain number of characters (no more, no less
  )!
- Symbol A - 2 count
- Symbol B - 3 count
- Note: characters and their count can be more than two (for example, C-1, D-2, E-32, etc)

I sketched all the combinations manually for an example:

```
aabbb
abbba
bbbaa
bbaab
baabb
abbab
ababb
babba
babab
bbaba
```

Comment: Hint:  Choose positions for the A's; from the remaining positions, choose positions for the B's.  Continue.

Comment: @Misha, Thank you very much, you're right, I missed it!